# Magento jQuery lightbox calling all thumbs from more views

Tags: magento, lightbox

currently I am using the extension from MagePsycho jquery lightbox. This extension is calling in the front end all the thumbnails and displaying as "more views" thumbs and I'd like to limit them. The code from the media.phtml is:

```
`<div class="more-views">
<h2><?php echo $helper->getConfig('more_views_label') ?></h2>
<ul>
<?php foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $_image):
        if(empty($popUpImageSize[0]) || empty($popUpImageSize[0])):
            $popUpImage = $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(),           'image', $_image->getFile());
        else:
            $popUpImage = $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'image', $_image->getFile())->resize($popUpImageSize[0], $popUpImageSize[1]);
        endif;
?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo $popUpImage; ?>" rel="<?php echo $rel; ?>" class="<?php echo  $class; ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel()) ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize($thumbnailSize[0], $thumbnailSize[1]); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel()) ?>" /></a>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

`

and a image describing the problem is attached. Thanks[image]

Comment: pretty tough to debug pictures.  would you mind adding your JS?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you already have all the information you need.

You have a loop that's going over each image

```
<?php foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $_image):
    //output thumbnail code snipped
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Instead of looping every item, you only want to loop four times.  There's lots of different ways to achieve this.  Here's one using a sentinel value

```
<?php $c = 0; ?> //define a counter
<?php foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $_image):
    //output thumbnail code snipped
    <?php if($c > 3) { break; } ?> //break if we've looped four times 
    <?php $c++?>                   //increment the counter
<?php endforeach; ?>
```